# Why do we need map() and apply() if we already have starmap()?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, apply, starmap

```
import multiprocessing as mp
pool = mp.Pool()
```

As I understand it (please correct me if wrong):

- `map` works on functions that take only one input parameter, and you
  can pass in a list of such single parameter to make multiple function calls
- `apply` works on functions that can take multiple parameters, but you
  can only pass one tuple of such parameters to make one function call
- `starmap` can deal with both multi-parameter functions and be passed
  in a list of tuples of parameters

Since `starmap` can handle what `map` and `apply` can, why does Python provide three functions instead of just one? In other words, what are the advantages of `map` and/or `apply` over `starmap`?

**Update**

As *@coldspeed* pointed out, it can just be backward compatibility. But this begs the question, and I guess this is what actually puzzles me: Why did python make both `map` and `apply` in the first place, what's so hard about allowing multi-parameter and a list of jobs at the same time?

Hope this is not closed due to being considered "primarily opinion based". There must be some reasons that can be universally appreciated why the original python developers made two functions each having its own limit instead of one single all-powerful one.